# in what way the following generic declarations differ in Java?

Tags: java, generics, static, comparable

I have two classes, one in which I have the `<T extends Comparable<T>` in the class header iteslf as `class MaximumTest2 <T extends Comparable<T>>` and another in which I have `public class MaximumTest` but the method extends Comparable as you can see in the code below.

1. In what way are the implementations different and is one better than other. btw , the way both classes above do the same thing.

   ```
   class MaximumTest2 <T extends Comparable<T>>
   {
      // determines the largest of three Comparable objects
      public  T  maximum(T x, T y, T z) // cant make it static but why??
      {                      
         T max = x; // assume x is initially the largest       
         if ( y.compareTo( max ) > 0 ){
            max = y; // y is the largest so far
         }
         if ( z.compareTo( max ) > 0 ){
            max = z; // z is the largest now                 
         }
         return max; // returns the largest object   
      }
   }
   public class MaximumTest
   {
      // determines the largest of three Comparable objects
      public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T maximum(T x, T y, T z)
      {                      
         T max = x; // assume x is initially the largest       
         if ( y.compareTo( max ) > 0 ){
            max = y; // y is the largest so far
         }
         if ( z.compareTo( max ) > 0 ){
            max = z; // z is the largest now                 
         }
         return max; // returns the largest object   
      }
      public static void main( String args[] )
      {
          MaximumTest2 test2 = new MaximumTest2();
          System.out.println(test2.maximum(9, 11, 5));

         System.out.printf( "Max of %d, %d and %d is %d\n\n", 
                      3, 4, 5, maximum( 3, 4, 5 ) );

         System.out.printf( "Maxm of %.1f,%.1f and %.1f is %.1f\n\n",
                      6.6, 8.8, 7.7, maximum( 6.6, 8.8, 7.7 ) );

         System.out.printf( "Max of %s, %s and %s is %s\n","pear",
            "apple", "orange", maximum( "pear", "apple", "orange" ) );
      }
   ```

   }

   1. when I try to make the method `public  T  maximum(T x, T y, T z)` static, I get the following error in Eclispe: `cannot make a static reference to a non-static type T`. I do not understand what this means? Can I not make it static?
2. Lastly, what is phrase exactly means `<T extends Comparable<T>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your first declaration makes `MaximumTest` [generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) whereas the second does not; that's a big difference from a programming standpoint (although when all is said and done and your code is compiled, the difference is erased -- that's why you can't declare a generic class and a non-generic class with the same name).

> cant make it static but why??

Sure you can; you just need to declare the type parameter `T` in the method signature as you do in your second declaration:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T maximum(T x, T y, T z)
```

`static` methods can know nothing about the type parameter of the instance, by definition.

> Lastly, what is phrase exactly means `<T extends Comparable<T>>`

In plain terms, it means `T` must be a type such that `T` instances are comparable to other `T` instances. Specifically, `T` must implement the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and consequently support the [`compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method, the mechanism through which the comparing is done.

Comment: `<T extends Comparable<T>>` declaring this again in the method (when I have declared is class header) is redundant correct? then what is the point of declaring in class header

Comment: @user1988876 It's not redundant; they're different `T`s, one belongs to the instance (the one in the class declaration) and one belongs to the static method. Static methods don't have access to the type parameters of the class they're defined in.

Comment: had been non-generic, I would have had `public static int maximum(int x, int y , int z)` and extrapolating that to generics, I should have had `public static T  maximum(T x, T y, T z)`. `T` here refers to some element type right. It could be `int` or `float`

Comment: @user1988876 It can't be a primitive, it would have to be the corresponding [wrapper class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class).

Comment: sorry, `T` cannot be int or float but `Integer` or `Float`

Comment: @user1988876 That's right, but be sure to declare `<T extends Comparable<T>>` to ensure that `T` is in fact comparable. Just `<T>` by itself means that `T` could be anything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36823/discussion-between-user1988876-and-arshajii)

Answer (score 2):

Static members of a class (such as static methods) do not inherit the class's type parameters.  So with `MaximumTest2`, if you were to make `maximum` static, then it wouldn't know what `T` is.  Your only option would be to make the method itself generic, but then you already did that with your `MaximumTest` class and its static `maximum` method.

When you say `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, you declare a generic type parameter with an upper bound.  `T` must be `Comparable`, and the specific type parameter for `Comparable` must be the same `T`.  For example, a `Foo` class that you'd like to use as `T` must implement `Comparable<Foo>`.

Comment: 'and the specific type parameter for Comparable must be the same T' ...It can also be a subclass.

Comment: @mike Not necessarily.  If you have class `Foo` that implements `Comparable<Foo>`, and you have class `Bar` that extends `Foo`, then `Bar` is `Comparable<Foo>`, not `Comparable<Bar>`, and you'll get `inferred type 'Bar' for type parameter 'T' is not within its bound; should implement 'java.lang.Comparable<Bar>'` if you pass `Bar`s to `maximum`.  The solution here is to modify the upper bound: `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`.